# Como aumentar a fonte do título de um gráfico seaborn.displot?

Tags: python, ipython-notebook, histograma, seaborn

Olá! Eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
f = sns.displot(df,x="yearOfRegistration", kde=True, binwidth=5) 
f.set(title = "Distribuição de Veículos com base no Ano de Registro")
f.set_axis_labels("Ano de Registro","Densidade (KDE)")

plt.show()
```

O resultado obtido é esse:

[image: Output]

Já tentei vários comandos diferentes que encontro na documentação do seaborn para aumentar a fonte do título, como **fontsize** ou **font_scale**, porém sem sucesso.

Alguém pode me ajudar? Desde já agradeço!

**EDITED**:

Consegui por meio do comando plt.title:

```
f = sns.displot(df,x="yearOfRegistration", kde=True, binwidth=5) 
plt.title("Distribuição de Veículos com base no Ano de Registro", fontdict = {'fontsize': 14})
f.set_axis_labels("Ano de Registro","Densidade (KDE)")
plt.show()
```

o seaborn.displot aparentemente não possui argumento pra aumentar o título.

Answer (score 0):

```
f = sns.displot(df,x="yearOfRegistration", kde=True, binwidth=5) 
f.set_title("Distribuição de Veículos com base no Ano de Registro" , fontsize = 20)
f.set_axis_labels("Ano de Registro","Densidade (KDE)")

plt.show()
```

Você chegou colocar um fontsize no método set?, Ele apresenta algum erro ou simplesmente não funciona??

Teste com esse meu código que modifiquei, por gentileza. Acho que o erro esta na so seu set na segunda linha

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei a respota! Segue o código abaixo:

```
f = sns.displot(df,x="yearOfRegistration", kde=True, binwidth=5)
plt.title("Distribuição de Veículos com base no Ano de Registro", fontdict = {'fontsize': 14})
f.set_axis_labels("Ano de Registro","Densidade (KDE)")

plt.show()
```

A dificuldade estava em utilizar o seaborn.displot. Com o pyplot.title resolve.

Agradeço a todos que responderam!